# Remove Secondary DHCP IP Address

Tags: networking, netplan

My system:

`Ubuntu 18.04`
`netplan 1.10.1-5build1`

My `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`...

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: false
            addresses: [192.168.1.8/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.1.1
            nameservers:
              addresses: [127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.8]
    vlans:
        vlan112:
            id: 112
            link: eth0
            dhcp4: false
            addresses: [192.168.112.5/24]
            nameservers:
              addresses: [127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.8]
```

How do I remove, and stop from coming back, the secondary IP (192.168.1.193/24) coming from DHCP that appears on eth0 in the following output?  I can't find anywhere that an interface is configured for DHCP yet the address can be seen here and I see DHCP client (`dhcpcd`) activity in `/var/log/syslog`.

```
user@localhost:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: vlan112@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:05:ff:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.112.5/24 brd 192.168.112.255 scope global vlan112
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 169.254.7.80/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global vlan112
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fe05:ff30/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
43: eth0@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:05:ff:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.1.8/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.1.193/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fe05:ff30/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does your host have a `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file?

Comment: I haven't found any other .yaml files that would be the culprit, nor have I found anywhere else that would be the cause.  So, I `systemctl stop dhcpcd` and `systemctl disable dhcpcd` and the address is now gone after a reboot.  But, I'd still like to know where it came from.

Comment: Yes, @Terrance.

Comment: That's the issue.  In that file you can add a line towards the bottom that states `denyinterfaces eth0` and that will stop the `eth0` interface from getting an extra DHCP address.

Comment: @Terrance, I tested your suggestion and it works.  Thanks for sharing the info.  Post up a solution for me to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a host has DHCPCD installed on it, it can cause the interface to still get an extra DHCP IP on the interface even though it is set to Static IP.

In the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file add `denyinterfaces <interface name>` towards the bottom of the file.

Example:

```
denyinterfaces eth0
```

This will cause the DHCPCD to stop sending extra IPs to the interface.

Hope this helps!